# YUI: Problem in file Upload and processing script..!

Tags: javascript, yui, javascript-framework

I have developed an interface in YUI. In which there is a form to upload a file on submit click.

```
YAHOO.util.Connect.setForm(document.getElementById('settings_Form'),true); 
YAHOO.util.Connect.initHeader('Content-type','text/javascript');
callbackFn =  {
 upload: function(html) {
  eval(html.responseText);
 }
};
YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST', 'pgRequests.php?t=settings', callbackFn);
```

pgRequests.php processes the file uploaded and returns some javascript codes like :

```
var servResponse = {"global_onOff":0,"off_msg":"OFF","id":0,"service":"Change Settings"};
```

But when "upload" is called, the 'html' variable contains the javascript code enclosed with
`<pre></pre>` tags. thats why eval() function is not working there.

I tried setting header in PHP file using :

```
header("Content-type: text/javascript; charset: UTF-8");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
$ExpStr = "Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() - 1) . " GMT";
header($ExpStr);
```

but didnt work.

I searched on google, but many people are facing the same problem. Thats why i cant figure out 
where its getting wrong.
What should i do to make it work? 
Is there any parallel way to implement the same flow?

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 1):

In your JSON encode -

```
replace < with &lt;
```

and also

```
replace & with &amp;
```

:p

Answer (score 0):

The YUI file upload occurs through an iframe. The responseText is the body of that iframe, hence where the `<pre>` tags come from.

```
       var responseNoPreTags = htmle.responseText.replace( /<\s*pre.*?>/g, '').replace ( /<\s*\/\s*pre\s*.*?>/g, '');
```

That should remove the `<pre>` tags aswell as any attributes. you should then be able to eval responseNoPreTags.